# find value in nested dictionary

Tags: python

Could anyone give me a tip on this on how find a nested dictionary key called `ven_id` and if it exists return the entire nested dictionary values?

```
ven1_id = 'ven_id_123'
ven2_id = 'ven_id_321'

def ven_lookup(ven_id):
     
     ven_info = {'ven1_info':
          {'ven_id': 'ven_id_123',
          'ven_name': 'ven123',
          'fingerprint': '7F:7F:7F:7F:7F:7F:7F:7F:7F:7F',
          'registration_id': 'reg_id_123'},

          'ven2_info':
          {'ven_id': 'ven_id_321',
          'ven_name': 'ven321',
          'fingerprint': 'G3:G3:G3:G3:G3:G3:G3:G3:G3:G3',
          'registration_id': 'reg_id_321'}
}
     
     look_up = ven_id in ven_info.values()
     if look_up:          
        return {'ven_id': ven_info['ven_id'],
                'ven_name': ven_info['ven_name'],
                'fingerprint': ven_info['fingerprint'],
                'registration_id': ven_info['registration_id']}
         
     else:
        return {}

   
print(ven_lookup(ven1_id))
print(ven_lookup(ven2_id))
```

If I run this it will return the False

```
{}
{}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.values()` will return something along the lines of `{'ven_id': 'ven_id_123', 'ven_name': 'ven123',...}`. `"ven_id_123"` is not this output. Because of this, it goes to the `else` clause. You will also have to change `ven_info[]` indexing in the `if` clause because of this same reason.

```py
look_up = [ven for ven in ven_info.values() if ven['ven_id'] == ven_id]
if look_up != []:
    return look_up[0]
else:
    return {}
```

This searches through the values of `ven_info` and if the ven's id matches the ID passed into the argument, it returns the correct dictionary you want. Otherwise an empty dict.

Comment: it's more pythonic to do `if look_up:` rather than checking if `look_up` is not equal to an empty list. Better yet, you could do `return look_up[0] if look_up else {}`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a generator expression to find the first matched value:

```py
def ven_lookup(ven_id):
     
     ven_info = {'ven1_info':
          {'ven_id': 'ven_id_123',
          'ven_name': 'ven123',
          'fingerprint': '7F:7F:7F:7F:7F:7F:7F:7F:7F:7F',
          'registration_id': 'reg_id_123'},

          'ven2_info':
          {'ven_id': 'ven_id_321',
          'ven_name': 'ven321',
          'fingerprint': 'G3:G3:G3:G3:G3:G3:G3:G3:G3:G3',
          'registration_id': 'reg_id_321'}
    }
    lookup = (v for v in venv.values() if ven_id in v)
    return next(lookup, {})
```

Where the second argument in `next` is the default value if no value is yielded

Comment: How could I incorporate a Boolean statement into your answer if the `ven_id` exists or not? On false just returns a blank dictionary

Comment: A blank dictionary can be treated as `False`. `not {}` evaluates as `True`. Otherwise, you could just swap the `{}` with `False`

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of trimming in the code, what I am doing is looking on each key of the dictionary using the .keys() method. For each key I check for equality with your entry string.
If I find the correct match I just extract the dictionary to the result variable and return it.

```
def ven_lookup(ven_id):
    result = {}
     
    ven_info = {'ven1_info':
        {'ven_id': 'ven_id_123',
        'ven_name': 'ven123',
        'fingerprint': '7F:7F:7F:7F:7F:7F:7F:7F:7F:7F',
        'registration_id': 'reg_id_123'},

        'ven2_info':
        {'ven_id': 'ven_id_321',
        'ven_name': 'ven321',
        'fingerprint': 'G3:G3:G3:G3:G3:G3:G3:G3:G3:G3',
        'registration_id': 'reg_id_321'}
    }
     
    for primary_key in ven_info.keys():
         if ven_info[primary_key]['ven_id'] == ven_id:
             result = ven_info[primary_key]
         
    return result
     
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(ven_lookup('ven_id_123'))
    print(ven_lookup('ven_id_404'))
    print(ven_lookup('ven_id_321'))
```